# How can I get my rails 4 categories to show on my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am trying to use the HABTM method in adding categories to my events in rails. For some reason its not working at all. Also whats weird my id field in active admin is filled with the title of my event not the id integer like so: `/admin/events/event-test`

I have this setup:

model/event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories 
    self.primary_key = :id
    has_attached_file :event_image, styles: {
        large: "600x450#",
        medium: "250x250#",
        small: "100x100#"
    }, :default_url => "/images/:style/filler.png"
    validates :title, :slug, :event_image, presence: true   
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end
```

admin/event.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event do
    controller do
       def permitted_params
          params.permit event: [:title, :slug, :event_image, :category, :eventdate, :description]
       end
       def find_resource
            scoped_collection.friendly.find(params[:id])
        end
    end
    form do |f|
      f.inputs "Details" do
        f.input :title
      end
      f.inputs "Event Date" do
        f.input :eventdate, :date_select => true, :as => :date_picker, :use_month_names => true
      end
      f.inputs "Category" do
       f.input :categories, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Category.all
      end
      f.inputs "Biography" do
        f.input :description, :as => :ckeditor, :label => false, :input_html => {  :ckeditor => { :toolbar => 'Full', :height => 400 } }
      end
      f.inputs "Image" do
        f.file_field :event_image
      end
      f.actions
    end
end
```

model/category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :events
    self.primary_key = :id
end
```

admin/category.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
    controller do
       def permitted_params
          params.permit category: [:id]
       end
       def find_resource
            scoped_collection.friendly.find(params[:name])
        end
    end
    form do |f|
      f.inputs "Details" do
        f.input :name
      end
      f.actions
    end
end
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "categories", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "categories_events", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.integer "event_id"
  end
```

events_controller.rb

```
class EventsController < InheritedResources::Base

    def index
        @events = Event.all
    end

    def show
        @event = Event.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

categories_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < InheritedResources::Base

    def index
        @categories = Category.all
    end
    def show
        @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

When I go to my view and try to access the selected category I get [].

Does anyone know what the issue may be here?

Comment: Looks to be an issue with strong parameters.

Comment: How can I overcome that? :(

Comment: Just a side note, but why are you doing this: self.primary_key = :id

Comment: rails4guides.com: because it was not allowing me to show my category dropdown on my events page